# Serverless framework 'dev' and 'prod' seperation

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am writing a backend service using the Serverless framework.

What is the best way for separating "Dev" and "Prod" environments?

Let's say I want my dev profile to deploy in a certain region and my prod profile to deploy in another? Is there a way to achieve this in the Serverless framework?

I would like to do something like:

```
serverless deploy --profile dev (--> use serverless-dev.yml)
serverless deploy --profile prod (--> use serverless-prod.yml)
```

Comment: CloudFormation would let you do this quite happily.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can deploy to different environments using stages with the serverless framework. The deploy command has the stage option which you can specify using `--stage` or `-s`. The option for region is `--region` or `-r` Here's an example:

```
serverless deploy --stage dev --region us-east-1
```

This option can also be used to deploy an individual lambda function to a specific environment.

```
serverless deploy --stage production --region eu-west-1 function --function helloworld
```

You might also want to use serverless variables to make your environment configuration dynamic. You can access environment variables using the syntax `${env:SOME_VAR}`.

There's also a way to make variables stage/region specific using nested variables.

From the docs:

> **Making your variables stage/region specific:**
>
> serverless.env.yml allowed you to have different values for the same
>   variable based on
>   the stage/region you're deploying to. You can achieve the same result
>   by using the nesting functionality of the new variable system. For
>   example, if you have two different ARNs, one for dev stage and the
>   other for prod stage, you can do the following:
>   ${env:${opt:stage}_arn}. This will make sure the correct env var is
>   referenced based on the stage provided as an option. Of course you'll
>   need to export both dev_arn and prod_arn env vars on your local
>   system.

**Links to serverless documentation:**

**Deploy**

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/deploy-function/

**Workflow recommendations**

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/workflow/#using-stages

**Serverless Variables**

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked 5 years ago and I assume back to the time there was not much support for multi-environment deployment using serverless framework.

---

Nowadays, there are few ways to achieve your goals:

1. Use of separate serverless.yml
   Assume you have two serverless.yml: `serverless.dev.yml` and `serverless.prod.yml`.
   You can run `serverless deploy --config=serverless.dev.yml` and  `serverless deploy --config=serverless.prod.yml` to use different yaml files. [For more, read this](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/deploy).
2. Use of stage in serverless.yml
   You can provide stage variable by using `-s` or `--stage` in your serverless command, like `serverless deploy -s dev`. You can then reference to this value in serverless.yml using `${opt:stage}`, in this example, it becomes `dev`. You can use this inline with the other string, like `${opt:stage}-User-Table` becomes `dev-UserTable`.
3. Use of param in serverless.yml
   If using stage does not satisfy you, you can use `--param` to pass a key-value pair to the serverless.yml. For example, you have `${param: TABLE_NAME}` in yaml, you can then set the value by, for example, `serverless deploy --param="TABLE_NAME=dev-UserTable"`. Like Method 2, the value is replaced by what you give in the command.

---

I think method 2 and 3 are the most suitable ways to do staging because you only maintain one serverless.yml, you only need method 1 in case you need multiple API Gateways in your service. You could imagine if you use `serverless.prod.yml` as stable version and `serverless.dev.yml` as development, when there is a release, you have to replace everything from `serverless.dev.yml` to `serverless.prod.yml`, which is not a good practice in terms of DevOps, use your VCS's branching function instead!

Hope this help!